# There is something wrong with my VScode after it upgrades to 1.5.1 its self

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter Notebook cannot run in my VScode after it automatically upgrades to 1.5.1 version. It says

```
Using the Jupyter notebook editor requires the stable version of VScode
and the CustomEditor experiment to be enabled.
```

I am not sure what's wrong with version 1.5.1 of VScode.

And I do not know how to let the 'CustomEditor experiment' to be enabled.

Comment: why post a picture of some text

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with stack overflow. I try to upload a picture, but it does not work. I type the error it shows by the VScode.

Comment: I just updgraded to 1.5.1 and got the same error.  I hope somebody knows how to fix this.